# contentResolver.query error on Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

I launched my app on the PlayStore. And I see in my developer console that a device runing Android 10 has an error. The log is the following:

[image: Error Log]

The error occurs in the contentResolver.query line of my `prepare()` method:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        Map<String, ?> carpetasMap = carpetasPreferences.getAll();
        String[] carpetasArray = null;
        StringBuilder selectionPlaceHolders = new StringBuilder(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?");
        carpetasArray = new String[carpetasMap.size()];
        int indice = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> asno: carpetasMap.entrySet()) {
            carpetasArray[indice] = "%" + asno.getValue().toString() + "/%";
            selectionPlaceHolders.append(" OR " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?");
            indice++;
        }
        if (carpetasMap.size() == 1) {
            selectionPlaceHolders = new StringBuilder(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?");
        }
        if (carpetasMap.size() == 0) {
            if (notClickedOnce) {
                carpetasArray = new String[rutas.length];
                //carpetas de musica al presionar boton por primera vez
                carpetasArray[0] = "%" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Music/%";
                if (rutas.length > 1) {
                    carpetasArray[1] = "%" + rutas[1] + "%";
                    selectionPlaceHolders.append(" OR " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?");
                }
            }
        }

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, String.valueOf(selectionPlaceHolders), carpetasArray, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            //falló el query, manejar el error
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // no media en el dispositivo
        } else {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            do {
                long thisId = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
                listaCanciones.add(thisId);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }
```

I ask for the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in my play() method.

I tried to reproduce the error on the emulator runing Android 10. But it runs perfect without no errors.

I tried to reproduce the error on a physical device (Galaxy Note 9) runing Android 10. But it runs perfect there too without no errors.

I tried the app on another phycical devices too runing Android 7, 8, 11, 12; and on all of them runs fine without no errors.

Can you help to find out what is causing the error?

Comment: Can you tell what your code should do? Can you also TELL which error you have?

Comment: You are making some assumptions about the internal implementation of the provider, such as it supporting `%` and `LIKE` and `OR`. `ContentProvider` is an abstraction, and the level of SQL that a provider supports, or if it supports SQL at all, is up to the implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare That code retrieves all audio files for the given path. Can you give an example of how I should retrieve them?

Comment: Don't try filtering via SQL. Do the filtering in your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm sorry, I'm noob at SQL. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the rest of the code.

Comment: @CommonsWare If i got you well, I could use a different `contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)` for every path stored in `carpetasPreferences`. Can it be?

Comment: You would `contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)` once and do your "does the `_DATA` column match my desired values" logic in Java.

Comment: Ok. I made it that way. Now how I know if the error is fixed? because I can't rerproduce the error. Or how I can reproduce the error of that user to see if it this solution fix the error?